# Python script stops working when I put it inside a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, django-1.9

Little bit of background: I'm using Python 2.7.12 on a Windows 10 computer.
This is by far one of the oddest problems I have ever encountered with Python.

I have written a script that makes a GET request to an API, with the correct headers, and gets some XML data back. For the record, when I paste the script like this in a python file and run it via CMD, it works perfectly fine.

But..

It stops working as soon as I wrap this inside a function. Nothing
   else, just wrap it inside a function, and use

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_new_function()
```

to run it from CMD and it won't work anymore. It still *works* but the API says I have wrong auth credentials, and thus I don't get any data back.

I went over every piece of string that is in this code, and it's all ASCII encoded. I also checked the timestamps, and they are all correct.

This is my script:

```
SECRET_KEY = 'YYY'
PUBLIC_KEY = 'XXX'


content_type = 'application/xml'
date = time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT', time.gmtime())
method = 'GET'
uri = '/uri'

msg = """{method}

{content_type}
{date}
x-bol-date:{date}
{uri}""".format(content_type=content_type,
            date=date,
            method=method,
            uri=uri)
h = hmac.new(
SECRET_KEY,
msg, hashlib.sha256)
b64 = base64.b64encode(h.digest())

signature = PUBLIC_KEY + b':' + b64

headers = {'Content-Type': content_type,
       'X-BOL-Date': date,
       'X-BOL-Authorization': signature}

r = requests.get('example.com/uri', headers=headers)
```

the same code inside a function:

```
def get_orders():
    SECRET_KEY = 'XXX'
    PUBLIC_KEY = 'YYY'

    content_type = 'application/xml'
    date = time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT', time.gmtime())
    method = 'GET'
    uri = '/uri'

    msg = """{method}

    {content_type}
    {date}
    x-bol-date:{date}
    {uri}""".format(content_type=content_type,
                date=date,
                method=method,
                uri=uri)
    h = hmac.new(
        SECRET_KEY,
        msg, hashlib.sha256)
    b64 = base64.b64encode(h.digest())

    signature = PUBLIC_KEY + b':' + b64

    headers = {'Content-Type': content_type,
           'X-BOL-Date': date,
           'X-BOL-Authorization': signature}


    r = requests.get('example.com/uri', headers=headers)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_orders()
```

Comment: shows us where and how you wrap this in a function.

Comment: I've updated the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your multi-line string is getting spaces in it when you indent it in a function. Concatenate it on each line instead and it should work.

Comment: What multi line string?

Comment: The value for your `msg` assignment.